# How to add a new function to crud controller in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Resourceful controller which there are default functions such as **index**, **create**, **store**, **show**, **edit**, **update** and **destroy**. My question is that how can I add my own function to that controller? For instance I add a function in that controller like this:

```
class Account extends \Eloquent {
.
.
.
        /**
         * Attempt login.
         * GET /accounts/login
         *
         * @return Response
         */
        public function login()
        {
            //
            echo "You are in login page";
        }
```

But it seems not work when i enter that url: account/login. This is my route file:

```
Route::resource('account', 'AccountsController');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a separate route for it, and the route needs to come before Laravel generates the routes for the resource controller.

```
Route::get('account/login', 'AccountsController@login');
Route::resource('account', 'AccountsController');
```

Comment: It worked but why it doesn't work when I defined url without 's' **'account/login'** ?

Comment: I have edited your answer by reversing their order and omitting 's' now it work perfectly. Thank you